# Why is there Big Red X in QGIS Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am working with QGIS version 2.01.  I created a print composer to export the map with legend, scale bar and title to an image or pdf.  When I opened my QGIS project again and went to my print composer there was a big red x which I can't see to get rid of.

Any ideas on went wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those "big red x" are usually an image where the file path is invalid. If you upgrade to QGIS 2.6 you now have a list of items on the composer shown. This is a big help finding and selecting 'hidden' controls on the composer page.

[image]