# Images missing in QGIS print composer template using mapped drive file path

Tags: qgis, printing, windows

My question relates to this previous question.
[QGIS Composer Big Red X](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133746/qgis-composer-big-red-x)
My images are missing when I load a print composer from a template 
and all I see is red X.  Investigating this further the problem only occurs when I used a mapped network location e.g. Z:\QGIS\Composers, if I look at the saved file path it incorrectly reads ../../GIS/Composers.  If I use the full path \\myserver\GISshare\QGIS\Composers then there is no problem and image loads correctly.

All users have the same mapped drive that they commonly use to work with and are trying to access templates and images from this same location.  All users are using QGIS 2.18 and Windows 7 or 10.  Does anyone know why QGIS won't save the mapped file path correctly in this case and if it can be resolved?